# "not authorized" with auth turned on in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am following the directions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04) to try and install Mongo 3.6 w/ authentication turned on.  I have added a "root" user and I am able to login using Mongo shell and I added a application user as well, but when I try to list DBs or collections using either `root` or the other userid I created I get the following error:

```
not authorized on on admin to execute command { listDatabase: 1.0, $db: \"admin\" }
```

I also get this when I try to login through my node app using the application user.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was two-fold:

1. I had added the app user to the wrong database. It seems like all users should be added to admin, not the database you want to grant permissions on
2. I was missing some roles on my "root" user.  The one that seemed to fix it was the "root" role
3. I was missing the role needed to list databases on my app user.  I added clisterMonitor and that seemed to work.

Those 3 together seemed to allow me to `show dbs`, `show collections`, and call `listDatabases` from MongoClient.